# rowExpansion inside datatable inside multiple tabs inside tabview referring to row object in last tab only

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:tabView` several dynamic `p:tab`, each of these tabs contain an identical `p:dataTable`. Ech datatable row contains a `p:rowExpansion`.

**Problem:**

When I click the rowToggler for any row it always uses the row from the last tab.

**Symptoms:**

If I go to tab1 and click expand on row1, then the contents are build using the row1 from the last tab.
If I go to tab1 and click expand on row10 where there is only 9 rows in the last tab, then the row object is null.

**Solutions?**

I understand that the rowExpansion is loaded lazily, so only once the rowToggler is clicked. Is there a way to prevent this and load the contents upfront? This would solve my problem perfectly.

Alternatively, is there a way to give the rowExpansion any hint as to which row it belongs to? Can I access the current rowKey or rowIndex in order to pass it on to the backing bean?

**What I tried**

Ideally, the tabs should be dynamic, so I use c:forEach and put my datatable under that.
I also tried to hardcode the tabs and use ui:include under those with my datatable in a separate xhtml file, but no change.

The closest question related to my problem I found was:

[Primefaces dataTable inside tabView the row selection not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100822/)

But there was no answer for it.

Here is what is looks like:

```
        <p:tabView rendered="#{controller.model.hasPerformances}"
                   styleClass="#{controller.fontClass} }"
                   activeIndex="#{controller.model.performanceIndex}">
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{controller.onTestTabChanged}"/>
            <c:forEach var="performance" items="#{controller.model.performances}">
                <p:tab title="#{controller.getPerformanceDisplayName(performance)}">

                    <p:dataTable id="testTable"
                                 var="row"
                                 value="#{controller.model.testData.getRows(performance)}"
                                 styleClass="#{controller.fontClass}"
                                 style="margin-top: 10px;"
                                 widgetVar="testTable">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <div style="height:30px;">
                                #{controller.getPerformanceTestTitleName(performance)}
                            </div>
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column style="width:1ch" class="tlga-table-column-expand" exportable="false">
                            <p:rowToggler/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:columns value="#{controller.model.testData.columns}"
                                   var="column"
                                   style="#{column.style}"
                                   styleClass="#{row.getCellClass(column)}"
                                   columnIndexVar="colIndex">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{column.title}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{row.getCellValue(column)}"/>
                        </p:columns>

                        <p:rowExpansion>
                            <p:dataGrid columns="3"
                                        styleClass="test-collapsed-area"
                                        value="#{row.collapsedCells}"
                                        var="collapsedCell">
                                <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="test-collapsed-value">
                                    <h:outputLabel value="#{collapsedCell.title}"
                                                   class="#{controller.fontClass} presentation-label"/>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{collapsedCell.value}"
                                                  class="#{controller.fontClass} presentation-text"/>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                            </p:dataGrid>
                        </p:rowExpansion>
                    </p:dataTable>

                </p:tab>
            </c:forEach>

        </p:tabView>
    </p:panel>
```

Comment: Which version of PF do you use? Can you narrow it down to make it a [mcve]?

Comment: I use PF 6.2.4 but if you tell me that a different version can do what I need, I may be willing to switch.

I have added an already very narrowed down version of my xhtml to the question, I cannot narrow it down any further. 

I meant to explain in detail what the problem is and I did originally not want to add any code but I was anticipating exactly this comment. I can further elaborate if any information is missing in my question.

Comment: Basically it really is just a nesting of p:tabView > p:tab > p:dataTable > p:rowExpansion being lazy loaded.